# Javascript using if(foo) exists to check if variable is set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I realize that this question is extremely similar to many others, but I must be missing some nuance with checking whether a variable is set or not. I have seen this in other developers code:

```
if(foo){
  doSomething(foo);
}
else{
  alert('error of whatever');
}
```

With the intent that the doSomething() will only execute if foo is set or not undefined. However, when I google this, it seems everyone says "typeof" should be used instead of the above method. I specifically see this in use with angular, like this:

```
if($scope.property){
  dothis();
}
```

Am I missing something? When I see the above code, it seems to work, but all the answers I see never say this is the correct way to check if something is set or exists.

Comment: You're likely to get subjective answers because your question in and of itself is subjective. Anytime I read something like _"...seems everyone says..."_ I usually consider the information to follow valid and potentially a best practice, but not the end all, be all and certainly not invalidating other methods for accomplishing the same goal. My point is that you should be mindful of the answers because you may not receive a concrete answer that you might otherwise be expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `if()` checks, in MOST scenarios where you are checking for the existence of a property on an object (your situation), what you have described is perfectly valid, easy and convenient.  It checks for the existence of the property and returns true if it exists.

However, there are plenty of nuanced areas where a typeof check is "more" correct, particularly if your type is being coerced in any way via `==` or if you want to differentiate between `null` and `undefined`.

For instance, if `null` is a valid value for your property to have but `undefined` is not, in your example `dothis()` would still be called.  You would prevent this with a `typeof` check.

```
if (typeof $scope.property === 'undefined') {
    dothis();
}
```

Finally, if you are checking for the existence of a variable instead of the existence of a property, an exception will be thrown if the variable you are checking is not defined, forcing you to use a typeof check.

In those scenarios, verbosity is your friend.

Comment: in your example you state undefined is not valid but you execute if property is undefined.

Comment: This actually addresses my concern very well. I would randomly get "is not defined" errors, rather than the "else" running, and it was because $scope itself was not set, so sometimes if($scope.whatever) would work and sometimes it wouldn't. The whole time my $scope wasn't being used properly!

Comment: @ChristianFischer In this case you would run IF the value is undefined, but not if null or valid, which is a common use case.

Comment: @hamncheez Glad my explanation helped!

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the concept of "[truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)". Any value **besides** false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN is "truthy" which means the first block of the if-statement will run. For instance:

```
if ("") {
    alert("falsie"); // won't run because the empty string ("") is falsie
} else {
   alert("truthie"); // will run
}
```

whereas

```
if ("something") {
    alert("truthy"); // will run because "something" is truthy
} else {
    alert("falsie"); // won't run
}
```

Going back to your example, if foo is truthy (meaning that it has ANY value other than false, 0, "", null, undefined, and NaN) then it will run the first block of the if-statement (which has the doSomething() function in it).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use short circuit evaluation and do this in one line.

($scope.property && doThis())

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `typeof` if you need to explicitly check whether the value is `undefined` or not. If you just want to check if the value is truthy, then you don't need typeof.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the typeof operator is preferred is because it doesn't throw a *ReferenceError* exception when used with an undeclared variable.

However, it is important to note that variables initialized as null will return "object", so to avoid this issue, the following code is recommended:

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined' || variable === null) {
    // variable is undefined or null
}
```

Comment: This is a bit misleading.  A ReferenceError exception will not be thrown for an undefined property of a defined object, which is the scenario that the OP described.

Comment: For sure, but the question was "Why is this considered the correct way?", and that is why. If the coder is not worried about the object they're checking being undeclared then they can check however they want. Knowing why something is helps understand when you can disregard the rule.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this is definitely misleading. The OP's code would ***not*** throw a _"Reference Error"_ in its current form. The answer to this question is subjective because the question itself is subjective. As @DavidL pointed out in his answer, the way the OP handles this is perfectly valid. There are other areas where a stricter type check or the use of `typeof` would be useful, but the original way is by no means the _"wrong way"_ or the _"non-preferred"_ way of handling this scenario. It should be handled on a case by case basis.

Answer (score -1):

What you are checking this way is if `foo` is not:

```
false
Undefined
Null
+0, −0, or NaN
Empty String
```

More info here:

> https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

This way your `function` is only executed if `foo` is valid.

You may want to be more specific and check against a certain `type` with `typeof`.

```
var foo = 'foo';
if (typeof foo === 'string') { // true
  doSomething();
}
```

> The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the
>   unevaluated operand.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof